# With GWT and Guice, is it possible to auto create an instance of an interface?

Tags: gwt, guice

If I have an interface like so

```
public interface MyInterface{
     public ThingA getThingA();
}
```

where ThingA is

```
public class ThingA{
    public ThingA(){}
}
```

With GWT and Guice is it possible to create a default instance of MyInterface without providing a concrete implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not in the normal way you might do it on a JVM - Proxy classes and other methods of generating an implementation at runtime are not available, but there is the `GWT.create` method, which will look through your rebind rules (declared in the module files that you create, and that you have `inherits` statements to include) and provide an implementation.

The easiest way to use these rebind rules is to just replace an interface or a class with some better implementation - this uses the `<replace-with />` tags, and you get to specify what to replace it with, and when you replace it. For example, when you are using Firefox, GWT automatically replaces its underlying dom implementation code with a gecko specific version:

```
<replace-with class="com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImplMozilla">
  <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImpl"/>
  <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/>
</replace-with>
```

This doesn't help you, but is useful to know.

The second way you can satisfy these is by declaring a `Generator` class to provide the implementation you want. Generators extend `com.google.gwt.core.ext.Generator`, and (usually) look at the class passed into them to create a new type and write it out, returning its fully qualified name, which is then used where you called `GWT.create(SomeClass.class)`.

In your case, you would want to look at the methods in the interface `MyInterface` and do something like call the default constructor for the return value of each. So to get an instance of MyInterface through the generator, ask for it like this, and use it as the interface describes:

```
MyInterface impl = GWT.create(MyInterface.class);
ThingA a = impl.getThingA();
```

To declare your generator, and that it should replace your MyInterface where it sees it, use a rule like this in your module file (by convention, just as GWT compilable classes go in a client package, generators go in a rebind package):

```
<generate-with class="my.package.to.rebind.MyInterfaceGenerator">
  <when-type-is class="my.package.to.client.MyInterface" />
</generate-with>
```

Beyond that, you'll want to look at what some other generators already in the GWT codebase do (or written outside of the core GWT team).

The original ImageBundle (superseded by ClientBundle now) is fairly simple in how it actually creates its source file with a `ClassSourceFileComposerFactory` and starts writing to the `SourceWriter`. The bulk of this can be found in the `generate` and `generateImplClass` methods of `com.google.gwt.user.rebind.ui.ImageBundleGenerator`.

GWT's RPC is generated by `com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.ServiceInterfaceProxyGenerator` and ``com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.ProxyCreator - this is a little complex to use to start with, but does provide some nice insights, including using a marker interface to generate with (instead of making a new rebind rule for each new interface, though they do nearly the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be possible because that would require bytecode creation, but in javascript there is no bytecode and reflection API is not available in GWT either.

Comment: Not sure why the down votes :) Because it's not possible *without creating a concrete implementation*. Having access to `GWT.create` and having a generator create the implementation is the same thing. You're providing a *concrete implementation*, only by creating the Java code from strings, so it's done at compile time. There is no way to do this at run time.

Comment: Yep, you are technically correct - though that work is done at compile time, and the results are not (generally) usable by code other than in GWT. The answer is valid, and helpful even, setting expectations about GWT, so I dont know why people would vote it down either...